# Que es un operador de asignacion en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operador

Ejemplo:

`a+=3(a=a+3)`

Eso es según lo que investigue, pero cual es la diferencia de a+=3 que decir a+3 lo mismo me pasa con las demás

Se que es distinto a decir `a+3` pero no encuentro el por que?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya hay una buena respuesta al respecto, sin embargo quice tomar tu pregunta desde otro punto de vista, pues quizá lo que ocurre es que estas entendiendo mal como se asignan las variables, pues leyendo bien tu pregunta conclui que enrealidad no estas comparando a:

`a+=3`

con:

`a=a+3`

Si no mas bien cuestionando: "Que sentido tiene que exista `a+=3` si ya existe simplemente `a + 3`?", **notese la diferencia**.

Quiza lo que te preguntas es mas bien, si puedo hacer que `a` cambie su valor simplemente sumandole `3`, entonces para que recurrir a:

`a+=3`

o

`a=a+3`

Y ese es exactamente el problema, que **estas asumiendo que `a + 3` es lo mismo que**:

`a+=3` y `a=a+3` lo cual por supuesto ni de lejos es cierto.

Te voy a dar un pequeño ejemplo para que me puedas entender:

```js
let a = 0;
a + 3;
console.log(a);
```

Como hemos podido ver en el anterior `snippet` si se ejecuta, **el resultado es 0**.

Es decir, `a + 3`, **NO** es lo mismo que `a+=3` ni tampoco que `a=a+3`.

Ahora veamos un ejemplo de `a += 3` y de `a = a + 3`:

```js
let a = 1;
    a += 3;
    a = a + 3;
    
console.log(a);   //7
```

Como vemos podemos ver una gran diferencia entre hacer: `a + 3`, y hacer `a += 3` o `a = a + 3`.

Y lo que esta ocurriendo aquí es que la primera sentencia (`a + 3`), es solo una **expresion matematica, una operacion, NO es una asignacion**, es decir, nunca estas cambiando el valor de `a`.

mientras que:

`a+=3`

y

`a = a + 3`

**son asignaciones**, y la forma mas facil de detectar que son asignaciones es porque hay un signo de igual, es decir, la primera expresion (`a + 3`) le suma a `a` 3 unidades mas **no almacena el resultado de esta operacion en la variable**.

Mientras que los dos ultimos (`a+=3` y `a=a + 3`) si que cambian el valor de la variable `a` porque le estamos asignando a la variable `a` por medio del operador de asignacion (`=`), lo que ya contenia mas lo que le estamos agregando.

Ahora bien, vamos a clarificar un poco mas eso de `a + 3` porque quiza con el primer ejemplo te puedes haber quedado un poco loco, es decir, seguro esperabas que `a` cambiase su valor a `3`, lo cual no ocurrio.

Sin embargo que pasa si hacemos esto?

```js
const a = 3;
console.log(a + 3);
console.log(a);
```

Como vemos aqui queda un poco mas claro, con una **expresion matematica** como lo es (`a + 3`) lo que cambia no es el valor que almacena la variable, sino que se crea un nuevo valor en base al antiguo, este nuevo valor es de uso subito.

Es decir, puede ser tanto almacenado como descartado al momento de su uso, esto es especialmente importante para cuando queremos hacer operaciones rapidas sin tener que cambiar directamente el valor de una variable teniendo como referencia base a esa variable.

Comment: loco sos un fenomeno, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de darme esa explicacion me quedo mas que claro, soy nuevo en la pagina y no se como agradecerte si hay algo para darte estrellas o algo asi, pero gracias.

Answer (score 2):

`a+=3` es una aberviación de `a = a+3`, esto se conoce en inglés como `syntactic sugar` o azúcar sintáctica; su función es facilitar la lectura y agilizar la escritura de código.

*Se que es distinto a decir a+3 pero no encuentro el por que?*

La diferencia es que al hacer `a+=3` estás reasignando el valor de `a`, en el otro caso no.

```js
let a = 0;
a+3;
console.log(`El valor de a es: ${a}`);
a+=3;
console.log(`El valor de a es: ${a}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

El `A+=3` es una abreviación de `A=A+3`. Es solo una abreviación de sintaxis que te ofrece *JavaScript*.

Comment: Es lo mismo básicamente

Comment: No solamente javascript, eso está presente en un montón de lenguajes

Comment: Claro si me expresé mal yo, lo tienen todos los lenguajes de programación